# Need help building an older version of firefox

Tags: linux, windows, python-2.7, firefox

I'm having issues building an older version (legacy requirements) of firefox.  Both bootstrapping and building fail using the mach tool.  Please could someone provide some guidance on how to solve the issues?

This is commit I'm building :

```
hg clone -r 239e434d6d2b https://hg.mozilla.org/releases/mozilla-release release
```

Mozilla build env is 3.1.1 (https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla/libraries/win32/MozillaBuildSetup-3.1.1.exe).

I could not find the documentation online to build this version, so have been trying the follow the latest documentation as a guide on what to do.
If anyone can point me to some documentation on how to build an older version, that would be great.

Here are the errors I'm getting:

```
'mach bootstrap' => 
    Could not find artifacts for a toolchain build named `win64-clang-cl`.
'mach build' => 
    File "c:/mozilla-source/release/build/moz.configure/init.configure", line 580, in split_triplet
      cpu, manufacturer, os = triplet.split('-', 2)
    ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

I assume the build error is because the bootstrap didn't complete.

Any direction on where to look to get around these would be really appreciated.

Many Thanks.

Comment: It turns out that the issue is with the `C:\User\<username>\.rustup` directory.
Running `mach boostrap` didn't populate this directory correctly (presumably due to the "win64-clang-cl" error - no explanation for this yet).  Luckily, I found someone who had an older version of this directory so was able to get past this build issues.

Comment: It is not about Windows only. I have the same issue on Ubuntu 18.04, but with `linux64-clang` instead of `win64-clang-cl`.

Comment: About triplet.split error:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1479540